# Is it legal to create / run a CS:GO jackpot site in europe?

Tags: european-union, gambling

Can there be any circumstances to doing so?

Comment: What is "a CS:GO jackpot site?"

Comment: Do you mean a site hosting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive tournaments?

Comment: I mean like a gambling site.

Comment: Update: Valve is now taking action against those who use their Steam accounts for commercial use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to host a gambling site in a country belonging to the European Union. For example, several gambling platforms are hosted in Malta, mainly because of the fiscal policy that the Maltese government applies on this kind of websites.

As the EU Commission itself remarks in its website, this topic largely depends on national laws. However, steps have been taken to introduce a common policy.

I suggest you to take a look at the Cooperation Agreement signed on 2015, November 27th, which you can find at http://ec.europa.eu/DocsRoom/documents/14259/attachments/1/translations/en/renditions/native . It is a bit long (161 pages) but it also includes references to the main laws regulating the topic for any Member State that signed the Agreement.

Comment: For some reason, im not able to open the file ;(

Comment: Weird. I could open the file from my smartphone, but not from my PC. If I manage to find another link, I'll edit my answer.